# Google Calender shows entry one day before

Tags: php, service, operating-system, joomla4

I am using Google Calendar API with PHP, and sending my bookings over to it.
But sometimes, it show booking one day prior to actual booking date i.e. when customer books for sunday it shows on Saturday at same time. It happens on random occasions not always.

My site is in Joomla4 and the component i am using is OS Service Booking. The developer of the component is not able to figuring out what is happening.

Pleas help me if you have any knowledge about such issue.

Thanks in advance.

The developer of the component has worked on it and he says everything is good on his end. His code has no issues and all other clients of his are happy.

Comment: We can't debug invisible code and data, sorry. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. See also the [tour] and [ask]. We're not a troubleshooting service, we won't sit here asking 20 questions about your scenario, and we won't answer with generic / speculative knowledge  which may not be relevant to your situation. You need to ask a specific question about a specific issue, which is demonstrable in the question via relevant code and data. Thanks.

Comment: *"i am using is OS Service Booking"* seems like they basically told you they are unwilling to help debug. *"Pleas help me if you have any knowledge about such issue"* no special knowledge as I don't work for them. ... Sounds like an issue however with them using UTC times never being transformed to their clients' local times. You can "correct" their snafu in your code if their API exposes the UTC times, but I don't really know what can or cannot happen with "OS Service Booking" tbh.